# When i save the figure as eps in matlab and install it in Latex file, it gives shady figure . Why?

Tags: matlab-figure

When I run the code in matlab, I have this figure.

[image]

But if I save the figure as eps and open this figure with GSview, the figure does not look so good as seen. There is a shadow and horizontal and vertical lines in the figure. And also when I put it as eps in latex file, it looks like the figure. I don't understand what the problem causes.

[image]

Comment: Depending on the renderer, it could look different at different screen resolutions and zoom levels. Try zooming in and out (e.g. zooming in on the problem areas) and see if the problem persists. Also, is the document for printing? Then print it and see if it looks OK on paper. Never trust your screen. If, on the other hand, the document is not for printing, then consider making either a high resolution bitmap image to include in the document, if that looks better and if the added file size is acceptable.

Comment: Another option is to make all lines a bit thicker. Set the line width property of all those circular lines to 1.5 (1 is default). By allowing a bit thicker line width you can help the renderer create smoother lines more easily.

Comment: Also, consider not using a rainbow-like colormap: https://www.google.com/search?q=why+rainbow+colormaps+are+bad

MATLAB's built-in `colormap(parula)` is much, much easier to look at, interpret, understand, natural, print in colour or black and white, and therefore simply better.